# How do I store number string as date time in Django's models?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to scrape videos on YouTube and save their uploaded date in the database. How can I take a number string (e.g., 05:22) value and turn it into a correct timestamp to store in the Django's models?

The only way I know how to turn a string into a time object is the code below:
    time.strptime('00:05:22','%H:%M:%S')

...but I'm not sure how that can be stored in the database through Django's models.

Comment: Wouldn't be a TIME column better suited for the length of a video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield). You can assign a `datetime.datetime` instance to it, and the ORM will handle the rest.

Or a `TimeField` for `datetime.time` instances, or `DateField` for `datetime.date`.